# Помогите с настройкой iptables для OpenVPN

Tags: linux, centos, администрирование, vps, iptables

Есть система с centos 7. На ней пытаюсь поднять OpenVPN. Возник вопрос с настройкой iptables.
Устанавливаю по [мануалу](https://1cloud.ru/help/linux/Kak-ustanovit-i-nastroit-OpenVPN-na-CentOS7)

iptables запущен и работает.

В мануале предлагают вбить правило

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Но в итоге добиться рабочего VPN не удалось.

В другом мануале предлагалось использовать правила:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o venet0 -j SNAT --to SERVER-IP
iptables -A FORWARD -i venet0 -o tun0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o venet0 -j ACCEPT
```

Они вообще убили сервер, пришлось ОС реинсталлить.

Перерыл инет и понял, что нужные правила не универсальны и зависят от того, какой сервер - выделенный или VPS, какая технология виртуализации хен или OpenVZ.

Подскажите, какие правила для iptables мне необходимо добавить, чтобы открыть 1194 порт и корректно заработал VPN на моем VPS с centos 7 и Virtualization Type OpenVZ.

Answer (score 1):

Правило из мануала точно не сработает, в OpenVZ контейнере надо использовать SNAT. Эти правила, которые "убили" сервер:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o venet0 -j SNAT --to SERVER-IP
iptables -A FORWARD -i venet0 -o tun0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o venet0 -j ACCEPT
```

точно рабочие и правильные. Вам надо проверить, использование tun/tap внутри контейнера разрешено или нет (чаще, по умолчанию, нет). У Вас точно интерфейс venet0?

Answer (score 0):

Вот такая конструкция работтоспособна

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o venet0 -j SNAT --to a.b.c.d
iptables -A FORWARD -i venet0 -o tun0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o venet0 -j ACCEPT
```

но нужно проверить что названия интерфейсов правильные (venet0 и tun0). По tun надо скорее всего просить хостера разрешить использование внутри контейнера.